# How to limit number of iterations from for loop

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am working on generating a XML report from API querying and I am hoping to get some guidance in limiting the number of iterations in "for loop".

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
import json
import os
import requests

dserviceIP = "192.168.1.80"
apiPort = "2000"
busName_ST = ("ST1", "ST2", "ST3", "ST4", "ST5", "ST6", "ST7", "ST8", "ST9", "ST10")
buses_ST = ("33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42")
listNumberOfEvents = "5" # Number of events to query in the list of schedules (Buses)
sessionID = "s12345"

def getSchedule():
    for bus in buses_ST:
        scheduleUrl = f"http://{dserviceIP}:{apiPort}/t/pa/{bus}/out?session={sessionID}"
        requestSchedule = requests.get(scheduleUrl)
        jsonRequestSchedule = json.loads(requestSchedule.text)

        scheduleID = []

        for scheduleIdList in jsonRequestSchedule['events']:
            scheduleID.append(scheduleIdList['id'])
            for eventID in scheduleID:
                eventUrl = f"http://{dserviceIP}:{apiPort}/t/pa/{bus}/out1/{eventID}?session={sessionID}"
```

example of response from **requestSchedule = requests.get(scheduleUrl)** , from the response I'm hoping to only extract the first 5 `id` to use it as the next part of my API HTTP query. see `eventID`

```
{
    "busid": "response_example",
    "events": [
        {
            "id": "X002"
        },
        {
            "id": "X004"
        },
        {
            "id": "X006"
        },
        {
            "id": "X008"
        },
        {
            "id": "X0010"
        },
        {
            "id": "X0012"
        },
        ...
        ...
        {
            "id": "X0248"
        }
    ]
}
```

expect the result of my `eventUrl` as

```
http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X002?session=s12345
http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X004?session=s12345
http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X006?session=s12345
http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X008?session=s12345
http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X010?session=s12345

http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X002?session=s12345
http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X004?session=s12345
...
http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X010?session=s12345

http://192.168.1.80:2000/t/pa/{bus}/out1/X002?session=s12345
...
```

Any advise in getting me through this roadblock is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list slicing like `[:5]`.

```
for event in jsonRequestSchedule['events'][:5]:
    eventUrl = f"http://{dserviceIP}:{apiPort}/test/buses/{bus}/events/{event['id']}?session={sessionID}"
```

Comment: Thanks both for promptly providing the pricise answer. exactly what I am after.
should i add it in :

`for scheduleIdList in jsonRequestSchedule['events'][:int(listNumberOfEvents)]:`
or
`for event in jsonRequestSchedule['events'][:int(listNumberOfEvents):`
?
presuming the first loop is more effcient?

Comment: you should add it in the first one